# Error running psi4 on charged molecules

Tags: computational-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, psi4

I am running a simple energy calculation on a conformer of 3-Sulfopropyl methacrylate, which is given my `C=C(C)C(=O)OCCCS(=O)(=O)[O-]`.

This is my workflow:

1. Generate conformers using genetic algorithm in OpenBabel

```
obabel -:"C=C(C)C(=O)OCCCS(=O)(=O)[O-]" -O SPMA.pdb --gen3D -d
obabel SPMA.pdb -O SPMA_op.xyz --conformer --nconf 300 --score rmsd --writeconformers
```

2. Extract coordinates of conformer, and put them in psi4 input file given by:

```
memory 8 GB
molecule MA0 {
0 1
  C          3.89733        0.15289       -1.35762
  C          4.59280        1.05052       -0.63907
  C          5.20105        2.27534       -1.24308
  C          4.74095        0.79591        0.82319
  O          5.01564        1.66100        1.64197
  O          4.54800       -0.52000        1.09100
  C          5.28200       -1.03600        2.21300
  C          6.78400       -0.89700        2.00000
  C          7.24307       -1.67225        0.77007
  S          6.44265       -1.12891       -0.72122
  O          6.80895        0.28345       -0.80582
  O          7.02056       -1.98627       -1.75252
  O          5.02989       -1.37699       -0.43672
  H          3.77090        0.29082       -2.37251
  H          3.48966       -0.67439       -0.89456
  H          4.99668        2.29431       -2.29321
  H          6.25936        2.26265       -1.08586
  H          4.78246        3.14570       -0.78247
  H          5.04197       -2.07085        2.34094
  H          5.00988       -0.47515        3.08265
  H          7.29461       -1.27505        2.86096
  H          7.00956        0.13820        1.85038
  H          7.02443       -2.70921        0.91770
  H          8.29303       -1.50198        0.65390
  H          7.75698        0.36077       -0.99601
  H          7.95459       -1.75656       -1.87793
}

set {
  scf_type          = df
  freeze_core       = true
 
}
E, wfn = energy('HF-3c', return_wfn=True)

oeprop(wfn, 'DIPOLE', 'QUADRUPOLE', 'MULTIPOLE(4)', 'MO_EXTENTS', 'MULLIKEN_CHARGES', 'LOWDIN_CHARGES', 'WIBERG_LOWDIN_INDICES', 'MAYER_INDICES', 'NO_OCCUPATIONS', title='Methacrylic acid (MA0)')

print_variables()
```

3. Now I run psi4 on this file:

`psi4 -n 2 -i SPMA_conf.in -o SPMA.out`

When I run this, however, I get a wall of error messages.

```
Printing out the relevant lines from the Psithon --> Python processed input file:
      H          7.00956        0.13820        1.85038
      H          7.02443       -2.70921        0.91770
      H          8.29303       -1.50198        0.65390
      H          7.75698        0.36077       -0.99601
      H          7.95459       -1.75656       -1.87793
--> ""","MA0")
    core.IO.set_default_namespace("MA0")
    core.set_global_option("SCF_TYPE", "df")
    core.set_global_option("FREEZE_CORE", "true")
    E, wfn = energy('HF-3c', return_wfn=True)
    oeprop(wfn, 'DIPOLE', 'QUADRUPOLE', 'MULTIPOLE(4)', 'MO_EXTENTS', 'MULLIKEN_CHARGES', 'LOWDIN_CHARGES', 'WIBERG_LOWDIN_INDICES', 'MAYER_INDICES', 'NO_OCCUPATIONS', title='Methacrylic acid (MA0)')
```

This seems to be the relevant portion of the error message...

I have run the very same process on other conformers of other non-charged molecules, but I have not run into this problem. Is it because 3-Sulfopropyl methacrylate is charged?

A similar problem arises when I run another charged molecule, like `C=C(C)C(=O)OCC[N+](C)(C)C`.

How can I fix this problem? Any advice you have would be appreciated!

Comment: Is there an error message beyond just the arrow pointing to that line? If it's not too long (e.g. hundreds or thousands of lines), you can include the whole error message or output.

Comment: @Tyberius, I figured it out actually. The ```0  1``` in the input file represent charge and multiplicity. the 0 represents charge, so once i change that to -1 for the first one, and +1 for the second one, it all works out.

Comment: Glad you got it resolved. I guess I should have looked at the input more carefully, it's pretty typical with electronic structure programs to specify charge and multiplicity in this way. In Gaussian, it will print an error message something like "multiplicity x is impossible with y electrons".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you already figured out, the error is that the charge and multiplicity are inconsistent with the molecule; this is what Psi4 tells you:

> qcelemental.exceptions.ValidationError: Inconsistent or unspecified chg/mult: sys chg: None, frag chg: [0.0], sys mult: None, frag mult: [1]

The problem is that the system has 111 electrons, which is an odd number, so you can't construct a spin-singlet wave function. Valid multiplicities for the neutral molecule are 2 (doublet), 4 (quartet), 6 (sextet), etc. The anion and cation both have an even number of electrons, so they can be in a singlet, triplet, quintet, etc.

Note also that `freeze_core` does nothing for self-consistent field calculations in Psi4.